# Determine con-/divergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1+2+\cdots+n}{2^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

**Problem:**

Determine if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1+2+\cdots+n}{2^n}$ converges or diverges.

**My attempt:**

I'm having a hard time with this one.

- Trying the ratio test, I'm unable to simplify the expression
- Trying the root test, I get the nth root of a sum, which I don't know how to simplify
- Trying the integral test, I'm having a hard time performing the actual integration
- Trying the (limit) comparison test, I can't find any reasonable expression to compare it with, but that might be due to the fact that I've been working on sequences like this for less than a day

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You can expand the numerator into (n(n+1))/2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that $1+\dots+n\leqslant n^2$, then you can conclude convergence with the ratio test.

Comment: Would this be a combination of the comparison test and the ratio test? I can probably conclude convergence for $n^2 / 2^n$, which is an upper bound on the sequence in the problem.

Comment: Yes, it is a combination.

Answer (score 10):

**Hint**:You can write the numerator $1+2+\dots+n$ as $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Comment: I'm literally ashamed!

Answer (score 5):

We can actually evaluate the sum using the binomial theorem (and negative binomial coefficients):
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1+2+3+\cdots+n}{2^n}
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\binom{n+1}{2}}{2^n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\binom{n+1}{n-1}}{2^n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{\binom{-3}{n-1}}{2^n}\\
&=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\binom{-3}{n}}{2^n}\\
&=\frac12\left(1-\frac12\right)^{-3}\\[9pt]
&=4
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

define $f(x)=\frac{4x}{(2-x)^3}$ write a Taylor's series to obtain$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n(n+1)}{2^{n+1}}x^n$$which converges on $|x|<2$, therefore your sum is $f(1)=4$.

Answer (score 1):

One more way is by using infinite GP, denote the required sum as

$S(x) =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k(k+1) x^k}{2}$, we want $S(1/2)$

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k =\frac{1}{1-x}, |x|<1$;
d.w.r.t x on both sides to get

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k x^k =\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}=f(x)$

Again d.w.r.x on both sides to get

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k^2 x^k = x f'(x).$

$S(x)=[f(x)+x f'(x)]/2=\frac{x}{(1-x)^3}.$

Finally we get $S(1/2)=4.$